# Unable to Vue.Js bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vue-component, mount

I'm trying to render bootstrap modal as a Vue.Js component. Please find code below. I've also pushed the code to a Git repo.

I keep getting the error.

```
testInstance.$mount is not a function
```

https://github.com/barrybonds/Test

Even though I have referenced JQuery and Vue.Js, I keep getting the error.
Please what I'm I missing.

Answer (score 0):

[`test.js` returns `Vue.component()`](https://github.com/barrybonds/Test/blob/b396052/js/test.js#L3), but that should be `new Vue()`:

```js
// return Vue.component('test-modal', {...}) ❌

return new Vue({...}) ✅
```

[See Pull Request](https://github.com/barrybonds/Test/pull/1)

Comment: Thanks @tony19 please the inital problem I wanted to solve that made me aske this question was this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67434314/button-click-doesnt-execute-vue-js-function
Please could you help answer it, it based on the code test code I helped me fix here